# Why do people seem to insinuate I would rather not use Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, std

Very often here on SO I see notes about boost such as

> If you are fine with using Boost...

or

> If you can use Boost...

And I wonder, what's that all about? What should I be weary of? When **can't** I use boost? What are the reasons not to use boost? In my opinion boost is a great extension to STL; sometimes very heavyweight and clumsy, but great nevertheless.

I am not really asking for opinions about boost as such. I am rather looking for some concrete examples when should I think twice before using boost.

Comment: `sometimes very heavyweight and clumsy` You answered your own question.

Comment: _"sometimes very heavyweight and clumsy"_ might be good reasons for small systems.

Comment: And that's it? Seems like a lot of fuzz for nothing :-/ By small systems you mean embedded systems etc?

Comment: @Jendas Mainly yes. But I tend to avoid boost for small programs also.

Comment: Boost is not a library but a **collection of largely independent libraries** of individual quality. Some of them are also redundant since C++11. Other than that, the usual caveats with 3rd-party libraries apply.

Comment: @Jamey: Might have done were that observation in any way true.

Comment: Boost's bcp tool lets you build only what you need for a particular library, and there's one code-based solution to stub out reliance on std vs. Boost or something similar, but I can't find it again for the life of me. Both of those should help with the heavyweight problem a bit, although portability across compilers and systems adds a different kind of heavyweightness.

Comment: Sometimes questions are about writing an implementation of an algorithm. The same goes for questions regarding writing a sort routine, which inevitably leads to the retort "why not use `qsort`?"

Comment: @Jongware: Or `std::sort`, given the C++ tag.

Comment: Perhaps you can phrase your question a bit less subjective? Like ask for the reasons to use or not use Boost. As it stands, it's rather opinion-based, in particular the title.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hah. That's nice. I tend to use boost for all prototyping/rapid development cycles. I rather think twice for long term production use. So, that's the opposite, really. Also, the things I use Boost for are rarely heavyweight. They may be clumsy (yes) but I hide that behind my own library layers.

Comment: At my old job, we were only allowed to use a few libraries (specifically, curl and ssl), in order to avoid having extra dependencies and keep things small. We shipped a library that was used by other people, and our customers had very specific requirements about a lot of things, including dependencies.

Comment: I'm very glad that people don't just propose Boost solutions to everything since not everyone has the luxury of using Boost...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> When I can't use boost? In my opinion boost is great extension to STL,
>   sometimes very heavyweight and clumsy, but great nevertheless.

Boost is not a library but a **collection of largely independent libraries** of individual quality. With this in mind, and also taking into account that I'm personally a big fan of most of Boost, here are some reasons I can think of for not using certain Boost libraries:

- Some Boost libraries are redundant since C++11.
- Some libraries are not widely used and thus require expert knowledge in your project which might be expensive to replace when an employee leaves the company.
- Company guidelines which developers have to obey more for political than for technical reasons.
- You have no guarantee that any Boost library will be continued to be maintained in the future. Standard C++ code written for some compiler today will very likely continue to work fine with a newer compiler by the same vendor 10 years from now, for simple commercial reasons. With Boost, you have to hope that enough competent people will have any interest in long-term maintenance.
- No Boost library is documented as extensively, with so much material in countless books and on the internet, as the C++ standard library. Who will support you if you have some really exotic problem with a particular library? Surely with standard C++ your chances of finding people with the same problem (and existing solutions for the problem) are much higher.
- Debugging some Boost code can be more difficult than debugging code that uses the standard library.

Comment: I bascially never see anyone recommend boost _as opposed to_ the standard library, except for a few specific portability edge cases. So I feel like the second half of your reasons are all not applicable.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, you can basically re-invent almost any Boost library with your own code, using the standard library. For example, you might use your own string algorithms library instead of Boost's String Algorithms, using what's available in `<string>` and `<algorithm>`. C++11 lambdas make this even easier than it used to be. I was not talking about all the direct replacements that came with C++11 (e.g. `std::shared_ptr` vs. `boost::shared_ptr`).

Comment: Perhaps add built times as argument as well. These Boost libraries have to work on many compilers while your shipped standard library only for the compiler it is shipped with. Spying Boost code it seems not have been a trivial task. We are replacing Boost code by std but actually I would have liked more Boost libraries to be std (e.g. calltraits, date-time, graph, signals, io_state saver, string algo, tribool. container)

Comment: it could be interesting to precise redundancy between Boost libraries and STL.

Answer (score 11):

Because it's *not* an extension to the C++ Standard Library (nor to the STL, naturally).

It is a third-party distribution, that you must download and install, locally and (for some Boost libraries, if you dynamically link) on the target system. You must manage and document the dependency.

I shan't enumerate all the scenarios in which this is not feasible, but it should be self-evident that you cannot always use non-standard code. Not everybody is working on a platform on which you can simply write `yum install boost-devel`, write your code and move on. The world of computers goes far beyond commodity desktop PCs.

That being said, most arguments for avoiding Boost are incredibly weak, due to its extreme portability, and the fact that the majority of Boost libraries are header-only (which reduces the packaging overhead significantly).

> Seems like a lot of fuzz for nothing

I don't think writing the phrase *"if you can use Boost"* can be honestly described as "a lot of [fuss]".

Comment: But Boost is the playground for improvements to the Standard Library. The same people maintain both.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: "The same people" is really carrying it a bit too far.

Comment: As the people who founded and maintain Boost are mostly C++ Standards Committee members as well, I really don't think it much of a stretch.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: But http://www.boost.org/community/index.html says: *"Although Boost was begun by members of the C++ Standards Committee Library Working Group, participation has expanded to include thousands of programmers from the C++ community at large."*

Comment: LOL. Nice cherry-picking. How about this one: "_**Is there a formal relationship between Boost.org and the C++ Standards Committee?** No, although there is a strong informal relationship in that many members of the committee participate in Boost, and the people who started Boost were all committee members._" Oh, or this one: "_We aim to establish "existing practice" and provide reference implementations so that Boost libraries are suitable for eventual standardization._"

Comment: @Dúthomhas: I'll ask you again. What is the relevance of who works on it?

Comment: @Lightness: I had only agreed with your assessment, adding that Boost is ultimately controlled ("maintained") by people who use it to further the future of the Standard Library (the _same_ people who decide what that is, mind you). Somehow this has inspired ire from Christian Hackl. The fact that _other_ people contribute to Boost does not mean that it isn't still ultimately a project by some people on the C++ Standards Committee, with the specific purposes of future improvements to the Standard. The _relevance_ is that this isn't just _any_ random C++ library. Sorry I posted at all...

Comment: @Dúthomhas: Nobody has "ire" towards you, and there is no need to get defensive. Chill out. And I maintain that its _political_ status as "not just another C++ library" has nothing to do with the technical considerations surrounding a decision on whether or not you may use it.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: I don't know where this supposed "ire" is coming from. As I said, I am a big fan of Booth and am enjoying this little discussion :)

Comment: I stand corrected. Sorry all.

Answer (score 9):

Maintenance mostly.

Once you add boost, you have to maintain it.  Either get updates (and maintain any changes mandating changes in your code), or freeze the version and fix bugs yourself.

Both are expensive and backloaded costs.  For a project with a lifespan measured in decades, such costs are highly important.

Comment: But that's true for any library you use, essentially. Plus, boost is and old, widely-used is widely-tested - at least the stuff that's not just-made-it-in, so it's unlikely you'll need to update boost other than to get new features.

Comment: @ein _"But that's true for any library you use"_ Right, and in the same scenario, I'd expect to see the phrase "if you can use <library name here>". So I don't think that's a reason to discard this! Indeed, the answer _is_ that a Boost library is no different from "any library you use", at least in this sense.

Comment: @einpoklum The problem also scales with, well, library scale.  A small narrow library has less to audit (is this component stable?), and tends to have less dependencies in your project when you update it.  Boost can easily be all over your project, and upgrading to fix a problem with the networking code could break your spirit-based parsing code elsewhere in your project (or, at the least, require an audit to make sure it doesn't break).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @LightnessRacesInOrbit's [point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453014/1593077), I'd say there are a few reasons:

1. Boost has a *lot* of code in `.h` and `.hpp` files, which you need to include in every translation unit (which uses the relevant parts of Boost), and those files are laden with complex and recursive macro use and smart - but again, complex - use of templates. The combination makes your compilation a w-h-o-l-e lot slower.
2. Boost isn't installed everywhere by default, so it's not always available to you just because C++ and the standard C++ library is.
3. (A new reason actually) A sizeable fraction of Boost functionality has made it into C++11 (more is in C++14, and still more in C++17). So, by now, there are alternatives in the standard library or even the language itself for part of what Boost offers.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think "you don't _have_ to use Boost" is equivalent to "you _can't_ use Boost [for x, y, z] reason"

Comment: Ad.1 You doesn't need include all of them. You need include only the ones which you are using. Most of the larger functionalities are also broken down into smaller ones, so you do not need to use large header files to handle simple single task.

Comment: @PsychoX: You don't need to include them all, but if you include just one, you pull in a lot; plus, Boost use can get a bit viral, for better and for worse.