# Any standard library implementation for boost::property tree

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, std, boost-propertytree

Is there an alternative to to ***"boost/property_tree***" ?

Actually I'm trying to remove all boost implementations of C++ and use standard library functions. 
I've been able to find alternatives to some other implementations of boost C++ but none so for property tree.

Motivation to not use boost: Mostly dealing with added dependencies

```
bool Processor::init(std::istream& xml, std::istream& rioxml, const std::string& logconfig, const std::string& recoveryConfig) {
    boost::property_tree::ptree config;
    boost::property_tree::ptree rioconfig;
    try {
        boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml(xml, config,
                boost::property_tree::xml_parser::no_comments);

        boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml(rioxml, rioconfig,
                boost::property_tree::xml_parser::no_comments);

        return Initialize(config, rioconfig, logconfig, recoveryConfig);
    }
    catch(const boost::property_tree::xml_parser::xml_parser_error& ex){
        LOG_ERROR(LOGCAT_DEFAULT, MSGID_UNKNOWN, "Failed to parse business config: " << logconfig);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not want boost ?

Comment: I think the motivation is mostly surrounding this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453112/7054831

Comment: boost is supplement to std - not a replacement or other implemenation - and to answer your question: No - and probably not in the near future either

Comment: You could always write your own replacement.

Comment: Are you only looking for something in the std library or are other third party libs not boost okay?

Comment: I'm looking for something in the standard library

Comment: From what I can see, you are attempting to use `ptree` as a convenient XML configuration parser. There is no known standard library equivalent for that. I suggest [this](https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2) as a _lightweight_ replacement. A discussion is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387610/what-xml-parser-should-i-use-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

I think there aren't any similar alternatives.

You can write you own implementation.